# How do I use the || operator in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, dbset, or-operator

How do I use the || (or) operator in a lambda expression?

Here is what I have tried:

```
db.assets.Where((u => u.userName.Equals(userName)) || (c => c.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker"))
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I am wanting to get a list of assets for the current user, as well as all assets that are for all users.  Assets for all users have a category of DefaultMapMarker.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: You have two different lambda expressions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it inside the body:

```
db.assets.Where(u => u.userName.Equals(userName)
                     || u.category.Equals("DefaultMapMarker"))
```

The way you did it would translate into "Lambda || Lambda" or "Func || Func"

Comment: @Sayse ofc - we don't know (and maybe this is wrong as `category` on a user(?) seems strange) - if not than the complete filter operation is very strange or impossible

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was wondering. Otherwise, The op would need two different queries (with the possibility of joining them together afterwards